# Does std::vector's push_back create a deep copy of the argument?

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, copy-constructor, mat

I have a list of images stored it several Mat objects and I need to push them into a vector of Mat.

```
vector<Mat> images; 
Mat image;
for ( i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
   \\ importing the i-th image into a mat image; 
   images.push_back(image);
}
```

Does this create a deep copy of the image?

Sure

```
vector<Mat> images;
Mat image (100, 100, CV_8UC(1), Scalar::all(255));
images.push_back(image);
image.release(); 
Mat temp (100,100, CV_8UC(1), Scalar::all(0));
image =  temp;
images.push_back(image);
imshow("black", images[0]);
waitKey(0);
imshow("White",images[1]);
waitKey(0);
```

this should show one black and one white image.

Another question

```
Mat img;
vector<mat> images;
for (i = 1; i < 5, i++)
{
    img.create(h,w,type); // h,w and type are given correctly
    // input an image from somewhere to img correctly.
    images.push_back(img);
    img.release();
}
for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) images[i].release();
```

This still makes me have memory leaks, what may be the reason behind it?

Comment: `.push_back` will copy the object. But here, the object is a `cv::Mat` object which itself is a matrix header, which is something like a "smart pointer". So you copy the smart pointer but not the matrix data values! Both, `image` and the copy of `image` will share the same matrix elements until one of them is reassigned new memory (which might happen if an openCV function needs more data). So no deep copy (of the matrix elements) is performed here, but you can't say for sure that both reference the same data forever.

Comment: Then I am confused. Since I always .push_back(image), i.e. the same matrix with different values, how can the vector images still contain different matrices (which I checked it does.)

Comment: can you provide some minimal sanple code to observe that behaviour?

Comment: Sure. 
`vector<Mat> images 
Mat image; `

Comment: Edited the original post and added a better code than above.

Comment: in your code you once oush_back image, then you copy temp to image variable (overwriting the variable but not the matrix elements) and then push_back image again (which now is referencing the matrix elements of  temp). remove the whole temp part, then push_back image twice and call image.setTo(Scalar (0,0,255) you'll see all 3 Mat objects (image and 2 in vector) to be red

Comment: So basically, after I release image, it may happen that the values of temp actually get stored in a place where the values of image have been and get a conflict/overload?

Comment: Also, if I remove the temp part push_back(image) then call image.setTo(Scalar (0,0,255) and push_back(image) again will it also transform everything into a red image?

Comment: I'll write an answer with some examples

Comment: btw, in your initial example you push_back only empty matrices. So they can't share any data at that moment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a little testing program to demonstrate the data-sharing properties of cv::Mat objects (which are matrix headers) in special!

```
int main()
{
    // create input of size 512x512
    cv::Mat input = cv::imread("../inputData/Lenna.png");

    // create a second input of size 256x256
    cv::Mat modifiedInput;
    cv::resize(input, modifiedInput, cv::Size(256,256));

    std::vector<cv::Mat> images;

    // first element will be a "deep copy" where the matrix elements will be copied to a new memory location and a new header will be created, referecing those matrix elements.
    images.push_back(input.clone());

    // 6 times copy the "input" to "images". 
    // All the copies will (deep) copy the matrix header but they will share the matrix elements (because their memory LOCATION will be copied)
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<6; ++i)
        images.push_back(input);

    // now some experiments:
    // draw a circle to input variable. At this point it should share it's matrix elements with images[1-5]
    cv::circle(input, cv::Point(100,100), 30, cv::Scalar(0,0,0), -1);

    // draw a circle to a vector element:
    cv::circle(images[5], cv::Point(300,100), 30, cv::Scalar(0,0,0), -1);

    // use a openCV function that will allocate new memory, if the destination dimensions don't fit:
    // to a mat whose dimensions fit:
    // remember that input.size() == vector[0..5].size
    // compute median blur and target one of the matrices that share their data at the moment:
    cv::medianBlur(input, images[3], 11);

    cv::imshow("0", images[0]);
    cv::imshow("1", images[1]);
    cv::imshow("2", images[2]);
    cv::imshow("3", images[3]);
    cv::imshow("4", images[4]);
    cv::imshow("5", images[5]);
    cv::waitKey(0);
```

At this time it's looking like this: All matrices share their element's data except the first matrix because there a deep-copy was forced with `.clone()`.

[image]

now continue with this:

```
    // to a mat whose dimensions don't fit (new memory will be allocated, not shared by the other matrix headers anymore):
    // images[3] will not share the data with other matrix headers afterwards
    cv::medianBlur(modifiedInput, images[3], 11);

    // now images[3] and images[4] will share matrix elements
    images[4] = images[3];
    cv::circle(images[4], cv::Point(128,128), 20, cv::Scalar(255,255,255), 3);

    // create a deep-copy of 256x256 input to overwrite images[5] (not modifying any other image's matrix elements)
    images[5] = modifiedInput.clone();
    cv::circle(images[5], cv::Point(0,0), 30, cv::Scalar(0,255,0), -1);

    cv::imshow("0", images[0]);
    cv::imshow("1", images[1]);
    cv::imshow("2", images[2]);
    cv::imshow("3", images[3]);
    cv::imshow("4", images[4]);
    cv::imshow("5", images[5]);

    //cv::imshow("input", input);
    //cv::imwrite("../outputData/MainBase.png", input);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

looks like this:
[image]

This time, the call of `medianBlur` did NOT share the data with all the other matrices, because the destination-image's dimensions DID NOT FIT, so new memory had to be allocated for `images[3]` within the medianBlur method. So images[3] referenced different data elements aferwards!

All this might be a little tricky because the user might not see directly, which function calls will allocate new data and which ones don't, so if you want to be sure to allocate new data, you should do this in beginning for each mat, or use an empty mat as destination (or don't share any data in the beginning).

One more thing:

```
cv::Mat emptyMat;
std::vector<cv::Mat> images(n, emptyMat); // insert n copies of emptyMat header
// or
for(unsigned int i=0; i<n; ++i)
    images.push_back(emptyMat) // same result
```

this is both save to use so that not data is shared, because all emptyMat doesn't have any data in the beginning, so no data can be shared. Whenever any data is assigned to any of the vector elements, the other's don't know about it and so they won't share that data.

```
// BUT:
cv::Mat notEmptyMat = cv::Mat::zeros(height, width, type);
std::vector<cv::Mat> images(n, notEmptyMat ); // insert n copies of emptyMat header which references the assigned zeroes data of size width x height
// or
for(unsigned int i=0; i<n; ++i)
    images.push_back(notEmptyMat ) // same result
```

Here, data is shared and whenever you change the DATA of one of those matrices, the other ones will be changed, too. But obviously, if you assign new data memory to one of those matrices, the other ones still reference their other data memory.

Comment: So the destructor Mat::release actually destroys the "header". How do I actually destroy the values of Mat objects?

Comment: OpenCV uses reference counting for the data. So when the last header of one matrix data is destroyed, the memory will be released.

Comment: Hi Micka, 
I have one more question regarding this setup. I am pushing mat objects into a vector, and then releasing them one by one, but still seem to have a memory leak. I thought that when refcount = 0 the memory gets deallocated.

Comment: @VahagnTumanyan can you post a full working (minimized) code sample (maybe in a new question) with this behaviour? If you do, please post a link here so I can find it =) For example post a main function where Mats are pushed to a vector and released afterwards with a memory leak occuring.

Comment: Mat img;
vector<mat> images;
for (i = 1; i < 5, i++)
{
  img.create(h,w,type) // h,w and type are given correctly
  // input an image from somewhere to img correctly. 
  images.push_back[img];
  img.release()
}
for (i = 1; i < 5; i++)
  images[i].release();

Comment: also here's a new question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34434401/avoiding-memory-leaks-while-using-vectormat/34434599?noredirect=1#comment56610282_34434599

Answer (score 8):

`std::vector::push_back` uses the object's copy constructor to insert an element into a vector. So if the Mat copy constructor creates a deep copy of the Mat object, you get a deep copy.

Answer (score 3):

It does not make deep copies, since `cv::Mat`'s are shared pointers. You have to use `clone()` or similar when adding to the vector `images`.

Answer (score 0):

[std::vector::push_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) will copy or move the object into the vector, that means the copy ctor or move ctor of `Mat` will be called. So it depends on `Mat`.

See [CopyInsertable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyInsertable) and [MoveInsertable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/MoveInsertable).