# Avoiding memory leaks while using vector<Mat>

Tags: opencv, memory-management, memory-leaks, destructor, mat

I am trying to write a code that uses opencv Mat objects it goes something like this

```
Mat img;
vector<Mat> images;
for (i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{
  img.create(h,w,type) // h,w and type are given correctly
  // input an image from somewhere to img correctly. 
  images.push_back(img);
  img.release()
}
for (i = 1; i < 5; i++)
  images[i].release();
```

I however still seem to have memory leakage can anyone tell me why it is so? 
I thought that if the refcount of a mat object = 0 then the memory should be automatically deallocated

Comment: @Miki the images that I put into the img are of the same type and dimensions, but are different images. Imagine doing something like imread(FileName) at each iteration.

Comment: ah wait.. your code looks broken, why do you call `img.release()` in the loop?

Comment: Yes, in the loop. since I also create it in the loop.

Comment: how do you measure the memory leak?

Comment: I basically create a packet for Mathematica. And have a code in that measures the memory usage before and after running the code. After the evaluation the difference should be 0.

Comment: not necessarily. For example if you push_back to a vector, the vector will remember and not reduce it's reserved size automatically even if you clear the vector (which you don't - you should call `images.clear()` in the end to free the memory of the matrix headers). I used your code to create BIG images, using 80 MB each. After running your code the consumed memory is about 4KB bigger than in the beginning before creating the first matrix data, so there is no matrix data present anymore because the leak should have a size of at least 80 MB in that case.

Comment: That means your matrix creation and releasing is ok and shouldnt create a memory leak. If there is a memory leak it isn't directly related to the matrix data creation.

Comment: For your code snippet: `for (i = 1; i < 5; i++)  images[i].release();` should create an error since indices will be from 0 to 4, so I changed to `for (i = 0; i < images.size(); i++)  images[i].release();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You rarely need to call `release` explicitly, since OpenCV `Mat` objects take automatically care of internal memory.

Also take care that `Mat` copy just copies creates a new header pointing to the same data. If the original `Mat` goes out of scope you are left with an invalid matrix. So when you push the image into the vector, use a deep copy (`clone()`) to avoid that it the image into the vector becomes invalid.

Since you mentioned:

> I have a large 3D image stored in a Mat object. I am running over it using for loops. creating a 2D mat called "image" putting the slices into image, pushing back image to vector images. releasing the image. And later doing a for loop on the images vector releasing all the matrices one by one.

You can store all slices into the vector with the following code. To release the images in the vector, just `clear` the vector.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    // Init the multidimensional image
    int sizes[] = { 10, 7, 5 };
    Mat data(3, sizes, CV_32F);
    randu(data, Scalar(0, 0, 0), Scalar(1,1,1));

    // Put slices into images
    vector<Mat> images;
    for (int z = 0; z < data.size[2]; ++z)
    {
        // Create the slice
        Range ranges[] = { Range::all(), Range::all(), Range(z, z + 1) };
        Mat slice(data(ranges).clone()); // with clone slice is continuous, but still 3d
        Mat slice2d(2, &data.size[0], data.type(), slice.data); // make the slice a 2d image

        // Clone the slice into the vector, or it becomes invalid when slice goes of of scope.
        images.push_back(slice2d.clone());
    }

    // You can deallocate the multidimensional matrix now, if needed
    data.release();

    // Work with slices....

    // Release the vector of slices
    images.clear();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using a deep copy is very costly in terms of time, I am aware that it creates a new header pointing to the same data. So to actually deallocate all data, I was thinking of explicitly releasing all headers. 

The documentation here says that  If the matrix header points to an external data set (see Mat::Mat() ), the reference counter is NULL, and the method has no effect in this case. I am not sure what that means though.
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=mat#void%20Mat::release%28%29

Comment: If you allocated data externally and just create a Matrix header on top of it, releasing the matrix will leave the original data unchanged. You need to explicitly deallocate orignal data also.

Comment: It will be much easier to answer properly if you show exactly what you want to do, and where your data comes from.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't post the actual code however conceptually what I am doing is the following: I have a large 3D image stored in a Mat object. I am running over it using for loops. creating a 2D mat called "image" putting the slices into image, pushing back image to vector images. releasing the image. And later doing a for loop on the images vector releasing all the matrices one by one.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Turns out I had been managing the matrices and their headers just fine, but due to some casts I had been getting memory leaks. Using ((raw_t_real32*)img.data)[i] casting to access the data of a mat object if img itself is per say unsigned 8 bit matrix is a very bad practice. I'll be using cv::Mat::at from now on.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code, which is basically what you do:

```
void testFunction()
{
    // image width/height => 80MB images
    int size = 5000;

    cv::Mat img = cv::Mat(size, size, CV_8UC3);

    std::vector<cv::Mat> images;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
      // since image size is the same for i==0 as the initial image, no new data will be allocated in the first iteration.
      img.create(size+i,size+i,img.type()); // h,w and type are given correctly

      // input an image from somewhere to img correctly. 
      images.push_back(img);
      // release the created image.
      img.release();
    }

    // instead of manual releasing, a images.clear() would have been enough here.
    for(int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++)
      images[i].release();

    images.clear();
}

int main()
{
    cv::namedWindow("bla");
    cv::waitKey(0);

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<100; ++i)
    {
        testFunction();
        std::cout << "another iteration finished" << std::endl;
        cv::waitKey(0);
    }

    std::cout << "end of main" << std::endl;
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

After the first call of testFunction, memory will be "leaked" so that the application consumes 4 KB more memory on my device. But not more "leaks" after additional calls for me...

So this looks like your code is ok and the "memory leak" isn't related to that matrix creation and releasing, but maybe to some "global" things happening within the openCV library or C++ to optimize future function calls or memory allocations.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Turns out I had been managing the matrices and their headers just fine, but due to some casts I had been getting memory leaks. Using ((raw_t_real32*)img.data)[i] casting to access the data of a mat object if img itself is per say unsigned 8 bit matrix is a very bad practice. I'll be using cv::Mat::at from now on.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered same problems when iterate openCV mat. The memory consumption can be 1.1G, then it stopped by warning that no memory. In my program, there are macro #define new new(**FILE**, **LINE**), crashed with some std lib. So I deleted all Overloading Operator about new/delete. When debugging, it has no error. But when it runs, I got "`Debug Assertion Failed! Expression: _pFirstBlock == pHead`". Following the instruction 
[Debug Assertion Error in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24881667/debug-assertion-error-in-opencv)
I changed setting from MT (Release)/MTd (Debug)to

`Project Properties >> Configuration Properties >> C/C++ >>` Code Generation and changing the Runtime Library to:

Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd), if you are building the Debug version of your code.
Multi-threaded DLL(/MD), if you are building the Release version of your code.

The memory leak is gone. The memory consumption is **38M**.